# Cufon / Jquery Parent Item only

Tags: jquery, cufon

I have a multi stepped navigation and I want to apply cufon to only the top level.

So it goes like this:

```
<ul>
     <li>
         <a href="#"> CUFON ME </a>
         <ul><li>sub nav, dont cufont me</li></ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Right now its selecting all the child elements, I just want the top level one to be selected.

```
Cufon.set('fontFamily', 'Museo Sans 500').replace('h1')('h2')('h3')('.menu-header ul#menu-main-nav li a');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the cufon syntax, but try

```
Cufon.set('fontFamily', 'Museo Sans 500').replace('h1')('h2')('h3')('.menu-header ul#menu-main-nav > li > a');
```

(though the `.menu-header` descentant selection is useless because the `#menu-main-nav` is an ID selector - or are there multiple elements with the same ID?)

This uses the [`>` child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) to make sure cufon is only applied to the first descentant, also called child.